# Princeton Review Math GRE Subject Test: Page 178 Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math

In Problem 3 on page 178 (Chapter 4 review questions on differential equations) one has to solve
$$
\left( \frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = \frac{x}{y} \left(2 \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{x}{y}\right).
$$
Now, the book does it by saying that the equation is equivalent to
$$
\left( \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{x}{y} \right)^2 = 0
$$
and thus we have to solve
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y}.
$$
Hence, the result is supposed to be $y^2 - x^2 = c$.

But if one tries to verify this,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 +c}}.
$$
Then,
$$ 
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +c}} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + c}}.
$$

So, I guess the question is what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you differentiate, there is a factor $\frac12$ that comes from differentiating the square root. (The derivative of $\sqrt{t}$ is $\frac1{2\sqrt t}$.)

It seems like you forgot this factor in your calculation of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't apply the Power Rule correctly:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x^2 + c}\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2 + c\right)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 + c\right)^{-1/2}\cdot 2x. $$
Actually, a better way to verify this is using implicit differentiation:
\begin{align*}
y^2 - x^2 & = c \\ 
2y\frac{dy}{dx} - 2x & = 0 \\ 
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{2x}{2y} = \frac{x}{y}. 
\end{align*}